# Can [gi] sound be at the end of an English word?

Tags: pronunciation

I am an Arabic person, and my family name is "Basrugi", but, what I know is that if the letter 'g' be followed by 'e', 'i', or 'y' it will be pronounced as /dʒiː/.

So, when an English person reads "Basrugi", he will interpret it as /basru:dʒi:/.

My whole point is there is a way or even a foreign character that can represent "Basrugi" pronunciation as /basru:gi:/ instead of /basru:dʒi:/?

Comment: If what you're asking for is a different English spelling of your name, try _Basroogy, Basroogie,_ or _Basrooggi_. None of these are ideal, but English spelling does not allow for ideal solutions.

Comment: Your assumption that all English speakers will read it as you stated is erroneous. Many of us have traveled, and know a second language (or more). It would not be difficult to recognize that name as foreign. I would have pronounced it *Bahsroogy*, and asked if that was correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the English language.

Answer (score 4):

The dog species "corgi" is pronounced with the "gi" sound.

We also have biggie, Fergie, leggie. They are all pronounced with the "gi" sound.

Comment: Also *fungi.* Another solution is to use the Italian hardener *h:* Basrughi.

Comment: @BrianDonovan You’d be amazed at how many people now use the spelling pronunciation *funji*.  The Italian solution is probably best here.

Comment: @tchrist--that's yet another good joke spoiled: "I hear Sam has a wicked case of athlete's foot." "Yeah, he's a real fun guy."

Answer (score 3):

There are many words and names in English that end with the sound sequence /-gi/. They can be grouped by their spellings. Some examples I pulled from [cmudict](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict)

**-GE**
KRESGE

**-GEE**
MAGEE
MCGEE
TUSKEGEE
PIGGEE
MUSKOGEE

**-GHEE**
GHEE
MCGHEE

**-(G)GIE** (note: -GGIE spelling only possible after 'short' vowels)
BOGIE
BOOGIE
BOOGIE-WOOGIE
DOUGIE
HOAGIE
CARNEGIE
AGGIE
BAGGIE
MAGGIE
PEGGIE
BIGGIE
FIGGIE
DOGGIE

**-GI** (note: mainly Japanese names)
TAKAGI
NAGI
KOGI
SHINOGI
CORGI

**-GHI** (note: names influenced by Italian spelling)
RIGHI
LONGHI
BORGHI

**-GHEY**
DONAGHEY

**-GGY**
AGGY
BAGGY
DAGGY
SHAGGY
CRAGGY
DRAGGY
WAGGY
LEGGY
PEGGY
REGGY
PIGGY
GRIGGY
TWIGGY
DOGGY
FOGGY
SMOGGY
GROGGY
SOGGY
BUGGY
HUGGY
MUGGY

Comment: But I'd pronounce "Donaghey" as "Donna-hey" or "Dunna-hey"

Comment: I guess there's also Alec Baldwin's character from "30 Rock", Jack Donaghy, pronounced /ˈdɒnəɡiː/